# Problems of memory developing games in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing a game for iPad. When I run the game on ipad and ride scene presence for the ipad automatically closes the application for lack of memory.
With TexturePacker converted images to pvr, but going from scene to scene'm not able to release memory.

```
[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
```

I am using these lines but not being enough.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Please consider:

1. Use instruments leak tool - try making snapshots at the same specific moment (for instance when you are ready to run your scene) then check what was allocated between them.
2. Try printing memory used by your application in specific parts of your program to find out where the memory is leaking.
3. Try to find out which dealloc's are not called when you remove your scene then go deeper.
4. Try calling general functions instead of unused ones:

   `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];`
   `[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];`

Comment: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames]; [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];

I am using these lines. Should I be making a mistake and I'm not noticing.

Any more ideas?

Comment: You may also try to add category to `CCTexture2D` and override `init...` & `dealloc` to update static `NSMutableArray`, then print it before you set up your scene. That way you might be able to see if any textures are still there not released. Important: Add them to `NSMutableArray` as non retained.

Comment: @TomaszZabłocki : I for one would not know how to add an object to an NSMutableArray without increasing its retain count. In fact, that is sure way to prevent textures from being removed from the cache.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: You can add objects to your array without retaining them with `[yourArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:yourObject]]`, then get it with `[[yourArray objectAtIndex:index] nonretainedObjectValue]`

Comment: @TomaszZabłocki : ah , interesting. thks

Answer (score 1):

After you remove unused textures, use :

```
[CCAnimationCache purgeSharedAnimationCache];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];

CCLOG(@"%@<applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning> : after purge", self.class);
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];
```

This will list the textures that are still retained in the cache, and the amount of memory they consume. Any texture that is still present when you expect it to be disposed, is probably there because somewhere along the lines (of code ;) ), you retained them 'somehow' (for example, adding them to an array).